# AspNet core Url decoding

Tags: asp.net-core, urldecode

I am using AspNetCore 2.1.
I encountered an issue to deserialize a portion of URL:
http://localhost:55381/api/Umbrellas/cc1892b0-b790-4698-ae3e-07bee39fd29b/ModeOperationnelWithAppliedEvents?dateDeValeur=2018-09-01T02:00:00.000+02:00

the part  "2018-09-01T02:00:00.000+02:00" is expected to be deserialized as DateTimeOffset. But it failed to do it. A default(DateTimeOffset) is returned.

If I encode to this format "2018-09-01T02%3A00%3A00.000%2B02%3A00" => correctly deserialized.

When it is enclosed in URL, that does not work.
In the contrarily, when the same format is enclosed in the body of message, it is correctly deserialized.

{"lastKnownAggregateVersion":4,"validFrom":"**2017-09-03T00:00:00.000+02:00**","commandId":"0cfa7da0-7895-4917-89ac-24ffa3abb87c","newDateDeValeur":"**2017-09-03T00:00:00.000+02:00**","eventUniqueIdentifier":{"streamName":"umbrella-54576b92-0234-4ec1-8eee-142375c53325","eventVersion":0},"aggregateId":"54576b92-0234-4ec1-8eee-142375c53325"}

According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) both colon ':' and '+' is legal char in a URL. Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok it turns out URL and URI have different standard

the URL standard is here [RFC1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). So according to the doc, ':' is reserved for scheme.

> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning:
>   their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a
>   designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is
>   reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";", 
>   "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be
>   reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may 
>   be reserved within a scheme.

and when it goes to +:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.

Comment: retested the stuff, it turns out both : and + can be decoded from URL.
But it seems that AspNet does not how to decode this format 2017-09-03T00:00:00.000+02:00 enclosed in a URL

Comment: + is considered as space in a URL